# Debugging Error 000725 for buffer and parameter not being valid?

Tags: arcpy, buffer, idle, error-000725

I am very new to Python.

I built a model in the ModelBuilder in a toolbox in ArcCatalog 10.3.1. I keep getting the following error about my buffer not being able to be executed and that my parameters are not valid. I set a field for a distance value for my buffer, my buffer, and a spatial join output as Model Parameters in my model builder before I exported the script to Python to run in Python IDLE:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "F:\Projects\Working\HurricanesSCRIPT.py", line 49, in 
>       arcpy.Buffer_analysis(Hurricanes_in_Counties, Hurricanes_Buffer, v15_Miles, "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "", "PLANAR")   File "C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 692, in
>   Buffer
>       raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000725: Output Feature Class: Dataset
>   F:\Projects\Working\ModelProject\ModelData.gdb\Hurricanes_Buffer
>   already exists. Failed to execute (Buffer).

I have already put in `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True` just below `import arcpy`.

Here is the script for my arguments:

```
# Script arguments
v15_Miles = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if v15_Miles == '#' or not v15_Miles:
    v15_Miles = "15 Miles" #15 Miles

Hurricanes_Counties_SpaJoi = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if Hurricanes_Counties_SpaJoi == '#' or not Hurricanes_Counties_SpaJoi:
    Hurricanes_Counties_SpaJoi = "F:\\Projects\\Working\\ModelProject\\ModelData.gdb\\Hurricanes_Counties_SpaJoi" # provide a default value if unspecified

Hurricanes_Buffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if Hurricanes_Buffer == '#' or not Hurricanes_Buffer:
    Hurricanes_Buffer = "F:\\Projects\\Working\\ModelProject\\ModelData.gdb\\Hurricanes_Buffer" # provide a default value if unspecified
```

And here is the script for my buffer:

```
# Process: Buffer
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(Hurricanes_in_Counties, Hurricanes_Buffer, v15_Miles, "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "", "PLANAR")
```

Comment: Why did you delete your other question?  That had valuable comments that will likely be rehashed on this question as people try to understand what you're doing.  Please [edit] this question and include all the extra information you were asked for on your deleted question

Comment: What is `Hurricanes_in_Counties`?  You have used this variable in your `arcpy.Buffer_analysis()`, but it is not defined in your arguments above.

Comment: As a new user it is unwise to delete questions because doing so feeds into the question limiting/banning algorithms that are run on the site. Doing it once will be OK but I advise strongly against doing it when you are far better to edit your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a check for whether the buffer feature class exists before you run your buffer.  You can use this check to delete the existing buffer, or just print a message.

```
# Script arguments
v15_Miles = "15 Miles" #15 Miles
Hurricanes_Counties_SpaJoi = "F:\\Projects\\Working\\ModelProject\\ModelData.gdb\\Hurricanes_Counties_SpaJoi" # provide a default value if unspecified
Hurricanes_Buffer = "F:\\Projects\\Working\\ModelProject\\ModelData.gdb\\Hurricanes_Buffer" # provide a default value if unspecified

if arcpy.Exists(Hurricanes_Buffer):
    print "{} already exists!!".format(Hurricanes_Buffer)
    arcpy.Delete_management(Hurricanes_Buffer)

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(Hurricanes_Counties_SpaJoi, Hurricanes_Buffer, v15_Miles, "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "", "PLANAR")
```

I have used `Hurricanes_Counties_SpaJoi` in place of `Hurricanes_in_Counties` in the Buffer as `Hurricanes_in_Counties` wasn't defined in your arguments.

---

Additionally, check the caps are in the right place in your `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`. This one (copied from your question above) is correct, however if the `O` from Output or the `T` from True are lower-case the overwriteOutput will not be set. Double-check that this is how you've used it in your script.

Comment: That worked. However, I got a new error but I'm going to see what I can do.

Comment: @MapsandCats take note of my comment about the variable names (right after my code sample) - this will be why you're getting a name error when you try to run it as per your other question.